# Using MiniProfiler in ASP.NET MVC 4 with EF5

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, mvc-mini-profiler

I tried EF Tracing Provider to check the SQL statements generated, but now I want to use MiniProfiler, but I'm not able to see the results...

What I made so far:

- Intalled packages:
  [image]
- Uncomment initialization in MiniProfiler.cs

> ```
> public static void PreStart()
> {
>     //...
>     //TODO: If you are profiling EF code first try: 
>     MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();
>     //...
> }
> ```

- Added the render in the layout view (before closing the body tag):

  ```
  @MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()
  ```

But nothing is showing in the browser relative to the miniprofiler...
I'm using database-first approach.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code should be added in the web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      //...
    <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```